# ClassNotFoundException when trying to step into JBehave stories in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, jbehave

I have a JBehave/Selenium/Serenity test wrapped by a maven project that I'm trying to step through in IntelliJ IDEA 14 Ultimate. When trying to debug, I get the following exception very early:

```
URLClassLoader.findClass(): ClassNotFoundException, name = "com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter"
```

The test runs fine when run through mvn integration-test.

I looked in /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar and /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar via jar tf, and was surprised that neither contained com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.

My question: What jar actually contains this class? What do I need to do to add it to my classpath?

Additional versions (from pom.xml)

```
JUnit: 4.11
net.serenity-bdd.serenity-junit: 1.0.44
net.serenity-bdd.core: 1.0.44
net.serenity-bdd.serenity-jbehave: 1.0.20
Using Java version 1.8.0_45-b14
```

Call stack for exception:

```
findClass():381, URLClassLoader (java.net)
loadClass():424, ClassLoader (java.lang)
loadClass():411, ClassLoader (java.lang)
loadClass():331, Launcher$AppClassLoader (sun.misc)
loadClass():357, ClassLoader (java.lang)
checkAndLoadMain():495, LauncherHelper (sun.launcher)
```

Some things I've tried:

- embedding all dependencies into the jar by using maven shade plugin
- embedding all dependencies by using maven-assembly-plugin
- adding .story files to .jar
- installing the JBehave IntelliJ plugin from https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7268?pr=

Related readings:

- [ClassNotFoundException in IntelliJ Beta (2009)](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/285178)

The command line that is being used to launch the test is

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:55965,suspend=y,server=n -ea -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/plugins/junit/lib/junit-rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:<project-specific dirs removed for clarity>" com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 com.mytests.Test1
```